# Can I substitute an Expression with a Symbol?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to check symbolically that the derivative of a sigmoid function is expressed by using its sigmoid function. I wrote below code which intends to substitute Expression as Symbol, but the output was not what I expected. How to do this substitution correctly?

```
import sympy

# define sigmoid functions
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
sigmoid = lambda x: 1/(1 + sympy.exp(-x))
sigmoid_deriv = sigmoid(x).diff(x)

# define symbol X
X = sympy.Symbol('X')

print(sigmoid_deriv.subs({sigmoid: X}))
```

output:

```
exp(-x)/(1 + exp(-x))**2
```

The desired output:

```
X*(1 - X)
```

Comment: I think `print(sigmoid_deriv.subs({x : f(sigmoid)}))` makes more sense, `f(sigmoid)` should be get from solving `sigmoid = lambda x: 1/(1 + sympy.exp(-x))`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @ComplicatedPhenomenon, it solved. Here is the code.

```
import sympy

# define sigmoid functions
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
sigmoid = 1/(1 + sympy.exp(-x))
sigmoid_deriv = sigmoid.diff(x)

# define symbol X
X = sympy.Symbol('X')

# solve inverse sigmoid function
eq = sympy.Eq(sigmoid, X)
x_lst = sympy.solve(eq, x)

# unpack result
x2 = x_lst[0]

# substitute x as x2
sigmoid_deriv2 = sigmoid_deriv.subs({x: x2})

# simplify `sigmoid_deriv2`
sigmoid_deriv3 = sympy.simplify(sigmoid_deriv2)

# print simplified sigmoid_deriv
print(sigmoid_deriv3)
```

output:

```
X*(1 - X)
```

Thanks.